# How to edit hotspot settings in Linux Mint 17?

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, wifi-hotspot

I am trying to create a soft hotspot in Linux Mint 17 (based on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS), but when I try I am not able to edit username/password for the created hotpsot moreover it is not detected by my mobile.

Below is the screenshot of Networking window.

[image]

**How can I get the options to configure my hotspot?**

**Or is there any other package available to do it better?**

Comment: Just a side comment : don't use WEP encryption. Never.

Comment: You may need to turn off the hotspot in order to edit the hotspot settings.  Try toggling it off.

Comment: actually i am not getting any ways to change the encryptio also

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the hotspot properties under 
"Main Menu -> Preferences -> Network Connections".

There should be an entry called **Hotspot**, which you can edit.

I also changed the "mode=infrastructure" to "mode=ap" under [802-11-wireless] in the /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot file.

Have a look at [How to enable Wi-Fi Access point on Mint 17](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1832) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to get the graphical tools to respect the ssid change, I was able to find a way to setup a wifi access point directly like so:

```
nmcli dev wifi hotspot ifname wlp4s0 ssid test password "test1234"
```

credit: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/384513/61349

Answer (score 0):

Make sure IPv4 settings are shared with other computers.

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo vi /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/YOUR_CONNECTION_NAME
```

Next change

```
mode=infrastructure
```

to

```
mode=ap
```

and save it.

Go to your

```
network_manager
```

Choose  "connect to hidden"